# sublime-text 3 unfolds on every save

Tags: sublimetext3

However I fold stuff in sublime-text 3, all the folds unfold on every save. Very frustrating. I have a pretty standard installation of build 3065 on ubuntu 14.04. Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't for me. Please [edit] your question with a list of plugins you're using, as most likely one of them is the culprit.

Comment: wish I knew how to get ST to print a list of installed plugins.

Comment: anyway, it turns out it only happens when I save to my additional SSD so will have to try to find out what is that about

Comment: seems to be connected to my Insync client to sync with google drive, but only with files on the additional ssd. hmmm.

Comment: To get a list of plugins, go to **`Preferences -> Package Settings -> Package Control -> Settings-User`** and they'll all be listed there.

Comment: Happens for me about half the time when working on a file over SMB mount